# Boundary contributions to the BTZ black hole hamiltonian

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hamiltonian-formalism, boundary-terms

I've been trying to understand every step of the (2+1 dimensional) BTZ black hole paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9204099.pdf ) but I'm stuck in the obtention of the boundary terms in the hamiltonian formalism. Concretely, in page 6 they argue

> One knows right away the surface term that must be added at
>   infinity without need to regularize.
>   For the Euclidean action, it is simply the
>   period $\beta$ of Killing time multiplied by the mass (by definition of the mass).
>   After infinity has been dealt with, there remains only to make sure that
>   the variational derivative of the action should vanish on the horizon. This
>   makes it necessary to include in $B′_{Euc}$ two further “surface terms” at $r = r_+$.
>   They turn out to be equal to minus two times the proper perimeter length
>   of the horizon (to cancel the variation of the hamiltonian constraint) and
>   $\beta N_\phi(r_+)J$ (to cancel the variation of the momentum constraint).
>   One thus gets for the Euclidean action                                               $I_{Euc} = \beta M − 4πr_+ + \beta N_\phi(r_+)J.$

I've been reading several papers related to hamiltonian relativity, ADM energy etc, but I still cannot manage to get closer to repeating that computation; usually they don't consider internal boundaries like here, and also the notation varies heavily between authors.

I have also tried to figure out the other way around, working back from the solution, but I just can't see how those end up being the results.

Comment: What is exactly your question? What step do you not understand?

Comment: I don't know what is the procedure or at least the first steps to obtain the results of their second paragraph, the cancellation of the variations.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.